# drupal 6 users table, some users' login timestamp are zero

Tags: drupal, authentication, timestamp, drupal-6

I'm trying to figure out an issue where the user's login timestamp are zero.  Their created and access timestamps are both set correctly.  What can cause this login timestamp to be set to zero?  We recently updated our drupal core with latest bug fixes, could that cause the timestamp to be set back to zero?  I tried search all over but couldn't find anything related to this.

The login timestamp will get set correctly again once the user logs in again. But there are some functionalities which relies on the timestamp to be set correctly and wanted to see how we can avoid this in future.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you by any chance found an explanation?